# Pagination not working

Tags: pagination

I have several pages with pagination in my site. The paginate tags are showing and clicking on the pagination links yields proper results

```
http:://test.com/foo/
http:://test.com/foo/P4

http:://test.com/bar/
http:://test.com/bar/P10
```

However, there is a page which has 3 segments where the pagination doesn't seem to work is intended

```
http://test.com/qux/lux/mux/
http://test.com/qux/lux/mux/P8
```

The pagination links are still generated properly. However, clicking on the pagination links always shows the first page.

Is there something wrong I am doing?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing some code.

Comment: Channel Entries Tag doesn't has a dynamic no parameter? But like Anna says we have to see the code...